# can WSGI get the full URL rather than simply : environ['SERVER_NAME'] ?.. if so.. Mod_Rewrite alternative?

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Currently..

```
 environ['SERVER_NAME']
```

can get the domain name. such as..

```
 domaint.tld
```

or

```
sub.domain.tld
```

but can it also get..

```
domain.tld/file/in/question.extension
```

also ?

if that is possible.. then can this somehow replace..  mod rewrite and do something like this..

suppose the url is

```
domain.tld/01
```

we split this at

```
 /
```

and then if it starts with 0 it must be something that we are looking for..
   use the number after '0'

to pull out variable content.

can this replace mod_rewrite ?

i do not like touching mod_rewrite due to complex stuff of regex..

Comment: This question is not very clear. All Python web frameworks have routing functionality and can process URLs however you like.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot really replace mod_rewrite if the intent is that the rewritten URL be fed back in as a sub request into Apache as a whole with request content still available. All you can really do is perform URL rewriting for use of the URL and request within a specific Python WSGI application.

The qualification on the first about request content is that when using daemon mode of mod_wsgi, it is possible to return a 200 response with no content and a Location response header, where the value of the Location header is a server relative URL. This will cause a new sub request to be performed at the Apache level, but in doing that it can only issue a GET request with no request content.

The 200/Location response can thus be used as a way for a WSGI application to reroute a request the WSGI application handles back to Apache to serve up a different resource, such as a static file or even a PHP application. This is by no means though a general mechanism that could be used to replace mod_rewrite and would only be suitable in certain use cases.

And on the specific point of access to other parts of the original request information, you have:

- SERVER_NAME
- SCRIPT_NAME
- PATH_INFO

See for example URL reconstruction in the WSGI specification at:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#url-reconstruction

Under Apache/mod_wsgi you also have REQUEST_URI, but that can be complicated to deal with as is not decoded nor normalised and can be a server relative URL or technically a URI format including scheme and host/port information.